# if condition is going wrong in golang

Tags: date, datetime, go

I'm calculating date difference in golang, I have written code and it is executing fine but when i take the difference of time in minutes, convert the same to integer and comparing in if condition.

code which im trying

as per the below condition, it should not print "diffinmin is greater
P" but it is printing. Where im doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    //fetching current time
    currentTime := time.Now()
    loc := currentTime.Location()
    //past time comes in as string
    pasttimestr := "2018-10-18 01:00"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04"
    //converting string to date
    pasttime, err := time.ParseInLocation(layout, pasttimestr, loc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Past Time: ", pasttime)
    fmt.Println("Current Time: ", currentTime)
    //differnce between pastdate and current date
    diff := currentTime.Sub(pasttime)
    var diffinmin int = int(diff.Minutes())
    fmt.Printf( "heloo",diffinmin )
    fmt.Printf("time difference is %v or %v in minutes\n", diff, diff.Minutes())
    var strconfigtime = "9000"
    var mininttimeconfig int
    if mininttimeconfig, err := strconv.Atoi(strconfigtime); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("i=%d, type: %T\n", mininttimeconfig, mininttimeconfig)
     }

    if diffinmin  >  mininttimeconfig {
    fmt.Printf("diffinmin is greater" )
    }

}
```

fiddle: https://play.golang.org/p/x6-RebYycpk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about scoping, the mininttimeconfig you are using in check has the value of 0.

```
if mininttimeconfig, err := strconv.Atoi(strconfigtime); err == nil {
    // mininttimeconfig is a new variable scoped to this block
}

// here mininttimeconfig is 0 from declaration line
// var mininttimeconfig int
```

Try changing the lines as:

```
    var mininttimeconfig int
    mininttimeconfig, err = strconv.Atoi(strconfigtime);
    if err == nil { 
       // ...
```

Or:

```
    mininttimeconfig, err := strconv.Atoi(strconfigtime);
    if err == nil { 
       // ...
```

Note generally error is used like if err != nil {...}